# Extract multiple values from html page for c#

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

I have this from html page source

```
<h5 class="icn-venue"><a href="/venues/mmxchi-tavernita-venue" class="pin-red place" data-lat="41.8938" data-lon="-87.633" rel="map">Tavernita</a></h5>
```

There are say 10 values like this between these tags on the page source.
I want to extract value between "h5" tags. Class="icn-venue" remains same for all values.
I tried splitting the tag and then storing but the code doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried using [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: I am not sure how to use that in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this using `htmlAgilityPack`:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourStream);

List<string> lst=doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h5[class='icn-venue']")
                    .Select(x=>x.InnerHtml)
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML Agility Pack is a great tool for manipulating and working with HTML: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

It could at least make grabbing the values you need and doing the replaces a little easier.

Contains links to using the HTML Agility Pack: How to use [HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)